# How to format the breaks on x-axis in forest_model in R

Tags: r, cox-regression, r-forestplot

I am using the forest_model function from the package forestmodel in R
I cannot figure out how to adjust the size and font of the breaks on the
x-axis as this does not appear to be a parameter in the function   (forest_model), nor does it seem to be something that can be specified
in the panels parameter...

```
forest_model(fit, 
             panels = mypanels)
```

I would like the breaks to appear bold and size 12 font.
Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the output of `forest_model` function is ggplot object which can be adjusted in the standard ggplot way.

I use the example provided by package forestmodel.

```
library(forestmodel)
library(survival)
library(dplyr)

pretty_lung <- lung %>%
  transmute(time,
            status,
            Age = age,
            Sex = factor(sex, labels = c("Male", "Female")),
            ECOG = factor(lung$ph.ecog),
           `Meal Cal` = meal.cal)

forest_model(coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ ., pretty_lung)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=12, face="bold"))
```

Comment: works perfectly, and now I think I understand ggplot a little better, thank you

Comment: @Jakub , is it possible to make the HR-squares proportional to the sample size of each subgroup? (the larger the N the larger the size of the square)